# Print amount of duplicates of each value in int array java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm new to java and has to finish this assignment. The question is, how can I from an array count all duplicates in a method and list them as so:

```
int [] arr = new int[] {2,5,6,1,2,1,5,3,6,1,2,1,5};
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

The values has to be sorted by integer and listed like this:

- 1 - 4
- 2 - 3
- 3 - 1
- 5 - 3
- 6 - 2

hope it makes sence.

Comment: Let us see what have you tried?

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. Show your effort.

Comment: Please show what you tried, also, have you looked into using a hashmap?

Comment: [what-have-you-tried-epidemic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic), I think 1 comment is enough and please try to pass constructive comments.

Comment: @Dazak I have tried so many different things but didn't make it work.. but YCF_L's version did the trick.

Comment: @yalpsideman not trying to get others to do my homework, i study thi to learn it, not take the easy way out. But its all fixed now thanks to YCF_L

Comment: @user3426191 I'm sorry, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `TreeMap` to keep the items sorted by key and just increment a counter for each occurrence.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Counter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 5 };
        Map<Integer, Integer> frequency = count(arr);

        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> freq : frequency.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%s - %s%n", freq.getKey(), freq.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static Map<Integer, Integer> count(int[] items) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int item : items) {
            map.put(item, 1 + (map.containsKey(item) ? map.get(item).intValue() : 0));
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Map like this :

```
int[] arr = new int[]{2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 5};
Arrays.sort(arr);
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Integer i : arr) {
    //if the key exit then increment it else add a new element
    if (map.containsKey(i)) {
        map.put(i, map.get(i)+1);
    }else{
       map.put(i, 1);
    }
}
//display your map
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    System.out.println(". " + key + " - " + value);
});
```

This will show you :

```
.1 - 4
.2 - 3
.3 - 1
.5 - 3
.6 - 2
```

Comment: Or `Arrays.stream(arr).sorted().boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1))).forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " - " + v));`

Comment: thank you @shmosel this is good

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line too.

```
Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet()).stream().forEach(e ->System.out.println(e + " -> " + Arrays.stream(arr).filter(x -> x == e).count()));
```